# Hibernate running random queries

Tags: java, hibernate

All, when I first call buildSessionFactory, Hibernate seems to be running a bunch of queries on my DB. They vary from being "selects" to "insert"s. Why is this and how can I stop it?

Edit: After some review, no the queries are not random. They seem to be inserts, selects and deletes into the tables on my DB. It almost looks like Hibernate is inserting a few records, running selects to make sure they were inserted and then deleting them.

Comment: What Hibernate version and what DB you are using? Are the queries really random, or are there repeated queries from one session to the next? What tables they affect?

Comment: +1, add these queries to the question

Comment: I would argue that your use of the word random is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the session manager starts it generates and caches a standard set of CRUD queries for the mapped objects. What you're seeing is (probably) just the logging of this query generation activity.

Comment: Is there any way to disable these? Or should I really care?